# Error while compiling a simple Java code

Tags: java, cmd, compiler-errors

So I typed the very first example of Deitel&Deitel's How to Java book which is

```
public class Welcome1
{
    // main method begins execution of Java application
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    System.out.println( "Welcome to Java Programming!" );
    } // end method main
} // end class Welcome1
```

Then I saved the file as `test.java` and went to its directory in cmd and typed `Java test.java` and I got the error `Error: Could not find or load main class test.java`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not compiling your code, compiler is `javac`, not `java`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two mistakes. Your class must match the file name. So move "test.java" to "Welcome1.java". Then you must compile it before you can run it.

```
javac -cp . Welcome1.java
```

Then

```
java -cp . Welcome1
```

Answer (score 4):

The file name needs to be `Welcome1.java`. Class names and file names need to match.

**Edit:** And as others have mentioned you have to actually compile your code with the `javac` command before trying to run it with `java`.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to compile the class with javac

```
javac Welcome1.java
```

Then you can call the class Welcome1

```
java -cp . Welcome1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class and Java file name must be the same. Like if you were to rename Welcome1 to test it would compile or rename the file to Welcome1.java it would compile.